# What is the probability of a least one person having 4 hearts given this circumstances?

Tags: probability, statistics, card-games

$4$ people $(A,B,C,D)$ receive $13$ cards each from a normal $52$ deck cards. If $A$ and $B$ have combined $9$ hearts, what is the probability of either $C$ or $D$ alone having the other $4$ hearts in their hand?

My way of thinking was:

there are 5 possibilities:

```
1) C has 0 hearts and D has 4 hearts
2) C has 1 hearts and D has 3 hearts
3) C has 2 hearts and D has 2 hearts
4) C has 3 hearts and D has 1 hearts
5) C has 4 hearts and D has 0 hearts
```

The only cases that satisfy are case 1 and 5. Therefore, my probability is 2/5.

People have pointed out that my way of thinking is wrong. What is the right answer to this problem?

Comment: Those cases are not equally probable (at least, they are not obviously so)  so you can't compute this way.

Comment: To think about @lulu's correct statement another way - if you flip a coin 9 times, the odds that you get 9 heads is not 1/10, just because there are 10 possibilities for the number of heads you got.

Comment: Most people have exactly one heart, except octopuses, who have three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider it this way:

The group formed by A and B have 9 hearts and another $13*2-9=17$ cards.

The rest of cards ($13*2=26$) are received by C and D. This 26 cards contain the 4 hearts remaining.

Now the question is how many combinations can you made of 13 cards taken from 26 that contains the available 4 hearts.

Take those 4 hearts apart. We have 22 cards remaining. 9 of them go to C (or D).

So C (or D) receives 9 among 22.

Calculate the number of combinations $N= \binom {22}{9}$ These are the "favorable" cases, because all of them have 4 hearts.

The total cases are $\binom {26}{13}$

So, the probability is $\frac {\binom {22}{9}}{\binom {26}{13}}$

But this is the probability for C. The question told "C or D". Then the final probability is $P= 2·\frac {\binom {22}{9}}{\binom {26}{13}}$

As @Barry Cipra commented, it can also be seen as "C has 4 hearts" $N_0=\binom {22}{9}$ or "C has no hearts (D has them) $N_1=\binom {22}{13}$.

And because $N_0=\binom {22}{9} = N_1=\binom {22}{13}$ we have $N=N_0+N_1=2N_0$ and hence a factor of 2.

Comment: It seems to me this is off by a factor of $2$, i.e., the correct answer is ${{22\choose9}+{22\choose13}\over{26\choose13}}$. Look at it this way: C has $26\choose13$ possible hands, of which $22\choose9$ have *all four* remaining hearts and $22\choose13$ have *none* of them.

Comment: @BarryCipra You are totally right. I've corrected my answer. THX.